# Converting to RData format in a loop with different dataframe names

Tags: r, for-loop

I wanted to write a loop to convert txt files from different folders into RData format. The files have the same name, so I wanted to rename them conditionally and save them to one folder. The loop does the job, but it saves the same name of the dataframe for all the files. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for (i in (sprintf("%02d", (seq(from=8, to=15))))) {
  for (j in 1:4){
    load <- paste0("C:/Users/User/Desktop/data/20", i, "/20", i, ".", j, "kw/data.txt")
    save <- paste0("data.20", i, ".", j, "kw")
    save <- read.table(load, sep="|", header=T)
  save(save, file=paste0("./data-r/data.20", i, ".", j, "kw.RData"))
  }}
```

Comment: I did, it was a typo. Different files are read each time, the problem is the name of df...

Comment: You're experiencing the non-standard evaluation at work in `save()`. The name of the df is given by the name of the object being saved which is in every iteration of this loop equal to `save`. You could use `saveRDS()` instead or switch to using the second rather than first argument to `save()` to specify the dataframe to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following adjustment of your code should do the trick.

```
for (i in (sprintf("%02d", (seq(from=8, to=15))))) {
  for (j in 1:4){
    load <- paste0("C:/Users/User/Desktop/data/20", i, "/20", i, ".", j, "kw/data.txt")
    save <- paste0("data.20", i, ".", j, "kw")
    assign(x = save,
           value = read.table(load, sep="|", header=T))
    eval(bquote(
        save(.(as.name(save)),
             file=paste0("./data-r/data.20", i, ".", j, "kw.RData"))
    ))
    eval(bquote(rm(.(as.name(save)))))
  }}
```

The `assign`-function ensures that the content of the file is assigned to the present value of your `save`-object.

The `eval` + `bquote` + `.()` + `as.name` construction is used to create (and evaluate) a call to the `save`-function, such that it does not save your `save`-object, but rather save the object whose name is stored in `save`.

The use of `rm` at the end is included in order to avoid cluttering up your workspace (and binding up memory) with the content from the files.